# Can all coding be done programmatically without using the Unity Editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In other game engines like Cocos2d-x, you can do all coding from Xcode, and don't need any editor.

Is it possible to build a unity game entirely through coding, and without using their editor ?

Is it possible to build a unity game without using the unity editor ? For example, can we use Visual Studio or Xcode ?

Comment: I recommend looking at the [answer to this question.](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/81699/91582)

Comment: Might as well start looking into Unity DOTS.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to create your entire game through just coding, with only minimal use of the editor for maybe setting up an entry point/some settings.

The bare minimum that I could think of that you need is a single object in the scene that has a "Main" script from which you start all other scripts. From there on out you can create every GameObject you need from code (`new GameObject()` (or even `GameObject.CreatePrimitive()` to save you some time on creating primitive shapes such as cubes/sphere etc)). The same goes for Components (`addComponent<>()`) and doing stuff like setting parents/ordering hierarchy.

As i've never attempted this myself I can not guarantee that all Unity/build settings can be set from a pure scripting perspective. The `UnityEditor` namespace gives acces to a lot of settings such as `EditorUserBuildSettings` etc. I've personally never come across a player setting or similiar setting that I wanted to set from scripting, but was unable to.

I suppose this would still require the editor to run in the background if you want to test in "editor" mode without having to rebuild your entire game every time you make a change.

As for building a unity game without using the editor at all I suppose it would be possible as long as you have the MonoBehvaiour Library in your project and you can define an entry point. However I don't know *how* this precisely would work. Or if it would build outside of the editor.

Comment: Example for an editor only setting you might want to set: IsStatic. That's an editor only feature. Thus you would have to live with more drawcalls. Also lightmap baking is only supported in the editor.

Comment: @Chillersanim you can set an object to static using `gameObject.isStatic = true;` which works at runtime (unless I missed your meaning). Lightmap baking is a good example. Though I wonder if you could somehow get editor scripts to run outside of the editor. if not that is indeed not possible.

Comment: GameObject. IsStatic is an editor only API, at least if one can trust the docs.

Comment: You can get the editor scripts to run outside of the editor, however, that typically breaks the terms of service of most Game Engines.  Not sure specifically about Unity about there are a few others that it does.  Curious I may just look into that now, I mean if it does violate the ToS.